# How to deal with large amount of data in API

Tags: php, mysql, api

I am developing a dashboard API for doing some operations related to users (create user, update, transfer money,...) by using PHP CURL to retrieve the data from an external source and display it to the front-end.
Everything was working well until the data started to grow at the database.

My senario is that each Admin after logging in to the dashboard should only do operations on his related users, that's why it takes too much time to retrieve all users from the source and then check the condition for related users and display them to this admin.

Is there a better solution for such kind of operations ?

I tried the following code to retrieve the data from the source and looped over requests since it's limited to 100 at each request.

```
function get_users($session_id){

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
      CURLOPT_URL => "THE_URL",
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
      CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>"{\"offset\": 0,\"limit\": 100}",
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "x-api-token: TOKEN",
        "Content-Type: application/json",
      ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $data = json_decode($response, true);
    curl_close($curl);

    $allcollection = [];

    foreach ($data['users']  as $key => $value) { 
     if(isset($value['admin']['id'])){
       if($value['admin']['id'] == $session_id){


        array_push($allcollection,$value);

      }
    }}

    $totalrows = $data['nrOfResults'];
    $offset = 100;

    while($totalrows >= 100){
        $newcurl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($newcurl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "THE_URL",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>"{\"offset\": ".$offset.",\"limit\": 100}",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "x-api-token: token",
            "Content-Type: application/json",
      ),
    ));

        $newresponse = curl_exec($newcurl);
        $newdata = json_decode($newresponse, true);
        curl_close($newcurl);

        foreach ($newdata['users']  as $key => $value) { 
            if(isset($value['admin']['id'])){
              if($value['admin']['id'] == $session_id){


                array_push($allcollection,$value);

             }
           }}



        $totalrows = $totalrows - 100; 
        $offset = $offset + 100;
    }



    return $allcollection; }
```

Comment: I'm confused. Where is the server side of this API? Is this an external service, or something you wrote?

Comment: It's a part of the code I wrote, this PHP function retrieve the data from the source database @AlexHowansky

Comment: Why not just make the database connection right from this app?

Comment: Just edited my question to be more clear, I am dealing with external data which I don't host.

Comment: Ah ok then, your main problem is that you are making one API hit per user. First step is to investigate the remote service's API docs and see if you can pull multiple users in a single hit.

Comment: No actually, I am getting 100 users each hit, then checking these 100 if they are related to the current admin.

Comment: You have a `curl_exec()` inside the while loop that iterates over users. You're making 101 API hits. If you can put that admin id filter on the first request, then you won't need the other 100, resulting in a performance increase of two orders of magnitude.

Comment: Alternatively, if you can you specify multiple userids to the user detail API endpoint, then you can do it in two hits.

Comment: (Or am I reading that wrong and the second hit is just for pagination?)

Comment: Yes, the second hit is only for pagination, since each response can carry 100 users, then I am reducing the counter by 100 after each response.

Comment: Ahh ok I see now, you're pulling *all* users, paginated, and then looping over all of them locally so that you can pick out only those that you want. So yeah, if you can specify that admin filter on the first hit, then you'll only have to wait for (and transfer) that admin's users instead of all of them. How many users total are there? How many users might one admin have?

Comment: It's about 10,000 users and each admin might have about 500 up to 1000 users. That's why I am looking for a better solution for it.

Comment: The API probably has a mechanism to specify your filter on the request. Using it will give you a 10x-20x performance boost. Other than that, you'd have to cache the user list locally and then keep it synchronized via a separate process that doesn't require a web user to wait. (Like via a job queue or cron.)

Comment: You are right ! I thought about using cron job for the solution you suggested, but the problem is that I have to update the cached data every 1 or 2 minutes to make sure that admins get updated data, and that may consume my server resources I think, no ?